# Excel - count unique days in a start-end date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Happy new year!

I have an Excel filled with start-end dates (**A2:B7**).
My interest is to try to get unique days in an interval.

I've made a research but I can't seem to find any solution to this, most of the threads are regarding searching unique days in a single collumn. But my interest is to get the unique days in a interval of start and end dates (**A2:B7**)

I've made the Excel as an example (below), with the expected result on the row F8. I also made a side calendar as an example (the days marked as green are the ones that the function should count).

Count Unique days in a date range

[image: Count Unique days in a date range]

I have no idea how to get this result using a function because of my limited knowledge of Excel.

Could anyone take the time to try and help me figure out how I can get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a VBA function to accomplish it. The function below calculates the number of unique days between given start and end dates. It takes them as arguments. It uses a dictionary to get dates from each row. It then removes dates that are not in the criteria. Finally, it returns the number of unique dates.

[image: Function UniqeDaysBetween]

```
Function UniqueDatesBetween(startd As Range, endd As Range) As Integer

    Dim d As Object
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim sdate, edate As Date
    
    'Create a dictionary
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Get last row of column A
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 2 To lrow
        'Get start and end dates for each row
        sdate = Range("A" & x).Value
        edate = Range("b" & x).Value

        While sdate <= edate
            'Add dates into the dictionary
            d(sdate) = sdate
            sdate = sdate + 1

        Wend

    Next x

    For Each vdate In d
        'Remove date if not in the range criteria
        If Not (vdate >= startd And vdate < endd) Then
            d.Remove vdate
        End If
    Next vdate
    'Get the number of unique days
    UniqueDatesBetween = d.Count
    
End Function
```

[image: Demonstration of UniqueDaysBetween function]

Comment: Hey Reddy, this works like a charm. Thank you so much.